# Checking if items are only in one list or multiple ones in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
display_list = ['display','screen']
water_list = ['wet','water','sink','Toilet']
crack_list = ['cracked','broke','broken']



for item in display_list:
    if item in problem:
        f_display = True
for item in display_list and crack_list:
    if item in problem:
        f_screencrack = True
for item in water_list:
    if item in problem:
        f_water = True
elif f_screencrack == True:
    print('You may need to replace your screen.')
    print('Note that if the crack is too heavy, you may need a new phone.')
```

I would like my program to be able to display a different answer if a user's answer can be found in both `display_list` and `crack_list`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator to check membership in a list.  Just check membership in both lists and combine them with a boolean and

```
if item in display_list and item in crack_list:
    ...
```

If you had a lot of lists to check memberships for, you can be a little more procedural

```
from operator import contains

if all(contains(x, item) for x in [display_list, crack_list, other_list]):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that using an if statement first worked quite nicely

```
 if item in display_list and item in crack_list:
     for item in display_list and item in crack_list:
        if item in situation:
            f_scrcrack = True
```